# Broken Link on Stack Overflow: Low Quality Posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, 404-not-found

The link

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/review-beta/low-quality-posts

leads me to the picture of a nice cat that says

> workin on ur problemz

Also

https://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/close

lead to a 404 page.

All of these links are presented on the page

https://stackoverflow.com/review

Comment: That is because those pages don't exist. Try removing the word `beta`

Comment: These links are presented on http://stackoverflow.com/review Removing `beta` from the first one does not solve the issue.

Comment: Those links (even with the beta) seem to be working for me.

Comment: @IAM I *think* that's because Geoff quickly added the routes. Sneaky Geoff!

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, thanks for catching that. I guess that after ±100 edits I wasn't paying enough attention anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few bumps while deploying our new review dashboard.  It should be working now.

Comment: fwiw, the links are broken for me as of now.